# i can't display my data from different domains in grails

Tags: model-view-controller, grails, groovy

i want to display data from multiple domain in grails. when i send my data to view it only executes or display the first "each" i am sending data like this

```
def list(){
    [user :User.list(), address: Address.list(), contact: Contact.list()]
}
```

my code for View is here

```
    <g:each in="${user}">

    First Name: ${it.firstName}
    Last Name: ${it.lastName}
    Email: ${it.email}

    </g:each>

    <g:each in="${address}">

    Permanent Address : ${it.perAddress}
    Present Address : ${it.preAddress}
    </g:each>

    <g:each in="${contact}">

    Mobile Number : ${it.phoneNumber}
    LandLine Number: ${it.landNumber}

    </g:each>
```

and the View Side is

Comment: have you double checked if you have any Addresses or Contacts in your db?

Comment: thanks for help, my address and contact params are not getting saved in db.

Comment: can you guide me how to save data into different domains with params while my domains are having relations. The User domain has following relation with Address and Contact domain `static hasMany =[addresses : Address, contacts : Contacts]`. In Contact Domain `static belongsTo = [user: User] ` and Address Domain having relation with User `static belongsTo = [user : User]` my code is
 `def save() 
{
def user = new User(params)
def address = new Address(params)
def contact = new Contact(params)
user.save()
address.save()
contact.save()
redirect action: "show" , id: user.id
}`

Comment: It's not related with an initial question. Add a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead (for example):

```
<g:each var="a_user" in="${user}">
    First name: ${a_user.firstName}
</g:each>
```

though I would rename your "user" to "users", "address" to "addresses", etc to make it more clear and idiomatic...

```
<g:each var="user" in="${users}">
    First name: ${user.firstName}
</g:each>
```

Comment: renaming to 'users' or 'addresses' is poor naming as it implies more than one tuple. In datbase design, the naming 'user' or 'address' are used to imply 'zero, one or more' and to not have implications about the data. But I WOULD say to rename 'user' to 'person' as some RDBMS's have 'user' as a reserved key word.

Comment: Hmm... but those variables are created via a User.list(), Address.list(), and Contact.list(). You're receiving an array/list of 0, 1, or more users, addresses, and contacts.  I might have a list of 'User' objects, but the convention where I work would be to name it users. You say 'tomatoe', I say 'tomahto;. Not worth worrying about except that a team should be consistent in its usage in a codebase.

Comment: 'list' is the function. 'User' is the object created from the 'User' Class based on the 'user' table. You can name it what you like but this is the naming nomenclature and standards used by database administartion and design.